# Not able to upload large files using plUpload

Tags: file-upload, plupload

Recently while uploading large files (in GBs) using PLupload, the file upload is aborted throwing `java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket` exception.

Any idea how to resolve this ?

> java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer.fill(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:152) at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:177) at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:110) at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractInputBuffer.doRead(AbstractInputBuffer.java:416) at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:460) at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:338) at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:395) at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:363) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:190) at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:997) at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:901) at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)